# How to pass object from controller to step in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to pass `reqData`  form My Controller class to Step of my job,Is there any way to achieve the same any help will be appreciated. I have a Object of `HttpRequestData` which i have revived in controller. Thanks

**HttpRequestController.java**

```
package com.npst.imps.controller;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.npst.imps.utils.HttpRequestData;
import com.npst.imps.utils.TransactionResponseData;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
@RestController
public class HttpRequestController {
    TransactionResponseData transactionResponseData;
    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;
    JobExecution jobExecution;
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    Job fundtrans;
    String test;
    @RequestMapping("/impsft")
    public String handleHttpRequest(@RequestBody HttpRequestData reqData) throws Exception {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        try {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
            jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(fundtrans, jobParameters);   
            ExecutionContext context= jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
            //context.put("reqData", reqData);
            transactionResponseData=(TransactionResponseData) context.get("transactionData");
            //System.out.println(context.get("transactionResponseData"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reqData+" "+transactionResponseData.getMsg()+",Tid="+transactionResponseData.getTid();
    }
}
```

Below is my step class

I want to get the same reqData in my step class and from here on wards i will put inside step Execution object of doAfter method.

**PrepareTransactionId.java**

```
package com.npst.imps.action;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.npst.imps.service.TransactionService;
import com.npst.imps.utils.GenericTicketKey;
import com.npst.imps.utils.HttpRequestData;
import com.npst.imps.utils.TicketGenerator;
import com.npst.imps.utils.TransactionResponseData;
@Service
public class PrepareTransactionId implements Tasklet,StepExecutionListener{
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrepareTransactionId.class);
    String appId;
    private static TicketGenerator ticketGenerator = null;
    private static GenericTicketKey genericTicketKey = null;
    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;
    @Autowired
    TransactionService transactionService;
    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String ticket;  
            System.out.println("transactionService:: PrepareTransactionId"+transactionService);
            TransactionResponseData  transactionData=new TransactionResponseData();     

            System.out.println("reqData::"+reqData);
            long value=transactionService.getMaxTid(appId);
            logger.info("Max id From db::"+value);
            if (value == 0) {
                value = System.currentTimeMillis() / 10000;
                long l = value;
                ticket=l+"";
            }
            long l = value + 1; 
            ticketGenerator = TicketGenerator.getInstance(9999999999L, 0, l);
            genericTicketKey = new GenericTicketKey(0, false, 10);
            ticket = ticketGenerator.getNextEdgeTicketFor(genericTicketKey);
            stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("ticket", ticket);    
            ticket=appId+ticket;
            System.out.println("tid::"+ticket);
            stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("tid", ticket);
            stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("reqData", reqData);
            transactionData.setMsg("Request Recived...");
            transactionData.setTid(ticket+"");
            transactionData.setNodeId(appId);
            transactionData.setReqtime(dateFormat.format(date));;
            stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("transactionData", transactionData);  
            logger.info("Request Recived with tid::"+ticket);
            ExitStatus exist=new ExitStatus("SUCCESS", "success");
            return exist.replaceExitCode("SUCCESS");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ExitStatus.FAILED;
        }
    }

    public String getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }

    public void setAppId(String appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I will not suggest to pass complete HttpRequestData. Rather than pass only requires information to batch. You can pass this information using JobParameters.

sample code

```
JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("key1",HttpRequestData.gteData)
                                                    .addString("key2",HttpRequestData.gteData)
                                                    .addString("key3",HttpRequestData.gteData)                                                 
                                                   .toJobParameters();
```

now in step you can get JobParameters from `StepExecution`

putting custom object in JobParameters

```
HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
           JobParameter myParameter = new JobParameter(your custom object);
           map.put("myobject", myParameter);
           JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(map);
```

Comment: is there any way to pass object

Comment: Yes , updated answer for  pass object as JobParameter

Comment: JobParameter myParameter = new JobParameter(reqdata);                       its not allowing to pass custom  object in jobparameter constructor.

Comment: @NaveenKumarMishra You have right. Based on spring documentation for **JobParameter**: `Only the following types can be parameters: String, Long, Date, and Double`.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR -> You can't.

[`JobParameters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html) instances can only hold values of types:

- `String`
- `Long`
- `Date`
- `Double`.

**The reason behind it is primarily persistence.** Remember that all spring batch metadata (including job parameters) goes to a datasource.

To use custom objects, you would need to make sure that your object is immutable and thread-safe.

[`JobParameters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html) documentation states:

> Value object representing runtime parameters to a batch job. Because
>   the parameters have no individual meaning outside of the JobParameters
>   they are contained within, it is a value object rather than an entity.
>   **It is also extremely important that a parameters object can be
>   reliably compared to another for equality, in order to determine if
>   one JobParameters object equals another. Furthermore, because these
>   parameters will need to be persisted, it is vital that the types added
>   are restricted. This class is immutable and therefore thread-safe.**

[`JobParametersBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParametersBuilder.html) documentation states as well:

> Helper class for creating JobParameters. **Useful because all
>   JobParameter objects are immutable, and must be instantiated
>   separately to ensure typesafety**. Once created, it can be used in the
>   same was a java.lang.StringBuilder (except, order is irrelevant), by
>   adding various parameter types and creating a valid JobParameters once
>   finished.

---

#### But i promise my objects are ok. Can I use them?

You could, but Spring developers decide to not support this feature a long time ago.

This was discussed in [spring forums](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/56579-dynamically-setting-the-resource-in-itemreader) and even a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-966) was created - status Won't fix.

---

#### Related Links

- [Spring - JobParameters JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html)
- [Spring - JobParametersBuilder JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParametersBuilder.html)
- [Spring - JIRA Ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-966)
- [Spring - Forums Discussion](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/56579-dynamically-setting-the-resource-in-itemreader)