# Accessing huge Multipartfile in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm trying to send huge multipart file in a Spring Image Batch Processing System.
I sent the Multipartfile[] to Controller and then Service. In Service I just set the files in a static Multipartfile array. And then started the job launcher.
In Reader I'm just accessing the static array and reading the data.

But my problem is I don't want to use static variable like that because I've to send huge amount of data in GB. So how can I call the read method from my Service so that I can send the data in parameter.

Here is my Service:

```
@Service
public class ImageService {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    public static MultipartFile[] files = null;

    public void imageFiles(MultipartFile[] files) {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addLong("startAt", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        try {
            ImageService.files = files;
            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                 JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is My Reader class:

```
@Service
public class MyCustomReader implements ItemReader<MultipartFile> {
    private int index = 0;

    @Override
    public MultipartFile read() throws Exception {
        MultipartFile[] files = ImageService.files;
        if (index >= files.length)
            return null;
        return files[index++];
    }
}
```

Here is my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private MyCustomReader myCustomReader;
    @Autowired
    private MyCustomProcessor myCustomProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private MyCustomWriter myCustomWriter;

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("MyStep").<MultipartFile, MultipartFile>chunk(3)
                .reader(myCustomReader)
                .processor(myCustomProcessor)
                .writer(myCustomWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job runBatchJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("batch")
                .flow(step()).end().build();
    }

}
```

I tried many way but can't solve.

Comment: The execution flow is not clear. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve without referring to Spring Batch? Is the image an input or  an output of the batch job? This is key to correctly answer your question.

Comment: input is multiple image array, and in output i want to store them in a folder of my desktop chunk-by-chunk. So how I pass the images from service to the reader class.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is huge, you should store it somewhere and pass the path to it as a parameter to your batch job. Here is an example from the documentation :

```
@Controller
public class JobLauncherController {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @RequestMapping("/jobLauncher.html")
    public void handle() throws Exception {
        // store multi-part file in a staging area
        JobParameters parameters = new JobParameters();
        // add path to input file as a job parameter
        jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
    }
}
```

Your item reader can then refer to it as follows (see documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#step-scope)):

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader flatFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[input.file.name]}") String name) {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Foo>()
            .name("flatFileItemReader")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(name))
            ...
}
```

Other Q/A that might help:

- [How to pass object from controller to step in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182018/how-to-pass-object-from-controller-to-step-in-spring-batch)
- [How to initiate a Spring Batch job from a RestController, passing an arry of Strings to the job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69066493/how-to-initiate-a-spring-batch-job-from-a-restcontroller-passing-an-arry-of-str)